# Illegal and legal forward reference in static block

Tags: java, static

I understand that this code doesn't compile because of an illegal forward reference.

```
public class StaticInitializerTest {
    static{
        staticVar++;
    }
    static int staticVar = 0;
}
```

But I don't understand why there is no illegal forward reference in this code.

```
public class StaticInitializerTest {
    static{
        staticVar = 12;
    }
    static int staticVar = 0;
}
```

P.S.: I'm using OpenJDK 1.8.0_66-b17

Comment: Maybe because there is no guarantee that staticVar has been initialized.

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3.

Comment: I think the key part of the spec is "The use is not on the left hand side of an assignment."